# Does each term of this sequence equal to zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

We define a sequence by recursion:
$$a_{2n}=a_{n}+a_{3n-1}$$
$$a_{3n}=a_{2n-1}+a_{4n+3}$$
$$a_{4n}=a_{3n-2}+a_{2n+1}-a_{n+7}$$

Question: Does each term of this sequence equal to zero?

I have proved $a_1=a_2=a_3=...=a_{17}=0$.

Comment: I don't even know the value of $a_{18}$.

Comment: Well yes they are all 0

Comment: How did you prove it?

Comment: Can you say a word about the origin of this sequence?